# Font-Awesome icons look strange in IE9 and IE8

Tags: css, webfonts, font-awesome

I'm using the font-awesome library for icons/buttons in my site.

Not using bootstrap, just plugging them in directly.

In IE9 and IE8, the icons double up and it's driving me bonkers!

Anyone know what this might be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some sort of text-shadow applied to the icons? Use the IE F12 devtools to try and track down exactly what CSS is being applied to the icon.

Also have you checked if you have *conditionally* included the IE7 font-awesome-ie7.css file using `<!--[if IE 7]>`? i.e.

```
<!--[if IE 7]> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fontawesome/font-awesome-ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I was just able to fix this... just now getting back to it. It seems that the ms-filter, filter: was causing issues so I just simply removed it. Thank you for looking into this!!!